# systemctl not working from shellscript but works from terminal

Tags: 14.04, scripts

`systemctl stop tomcat_tomcat9.service`

If I issue the above comand from terminal it is working but if it is executed from shell script I get the below error.

`Invalid unit name "tomcat_tomcat9.service " escaped as "tomcat_tomcat9.service\x0d" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?). Failed to stop tomcat_tomcat9.service\x0d.service: Unit tomcat_tomcat9.service\x0d.service not loaded.`

Comment: see https://serverfault.com/questions/1094756/run-commands-that-run-in-a-shell-as-a-script, did you edit the shell script from Windows?

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/   *You've tagged your release as an EOL/ESM release - is that what you're using?  as it doesn't include `systemctl` (systemd) by default*

Answer (score 1):

> Invalid unit name "tomcat_tomcat9.service " escaped as "tomcat_tomcat9.service\x0d"

translates that systemd sees(1) your service followed by a carriage return which moves the cursor (<) to the beginning of the line.

```
tomcat_tomcat9.service
>
```

The reason might be that the script is written in windows. Some text editors add \r\n invisible when you start a new line. Systemd sees that \r part and notifies you:

```
 escaped as "tomcat_tomcat9.service\x0d" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
```

The solution is simple, delete the `e "` from the end and type `e"` in your script and save it.

You can use the command systemd-escape to test it if you want:

```
$ systemd-escape "tomcat_tomcat9.service"
  tomcat_tomcat9.service
```

Should be the outcome. From systemd point of view the "" are not needed.

```
$ systemd-escape tomcat_tomcat9.service
tomcat_tomcat9.service
```

You get the same output without the quotes.

(1) Adding a carriage return and " translates in servicename and a new line

```
user@hostname:~$ systemd-escape -u "tomcat_tomcat9.service
> "
tomcat_tomcat9.service

user@hostname:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test anything of this, but from your error message I'm pretty confident, that there is some whitespace character at the end as it is written "...service " instead of "...service".

Comment: `\x0d` is Carriage return.

Comment: Then adding a space at the end might solve the problem as in this case, it terminates the argument.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Notepad++ in windows for editing .sh file. Resovled it by changing EOL Conversion (Option Under Edit Menu) to Unix(LF).